# Why FileExtensionContentTypeProvider no work with .min.js extension?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some css&js files in my project and I used the `BuildBundlerMinifier` NuGet package to minify and obfuscate them.

For example, the `app.js` will minify and obfuscate into `app.min.js` in the same directory.

Now I want the user can access the `app.min.js` but can't access the `app.js`.

I do this for I don't want anybody else to access the source code of my js.

Although someone still can get its source code from the `app.min.js` while I don't want them to get it easily.

I tried to use `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` in `Configure` of `startup.cs` to achieve this:

```
 var provider = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings.Remove(".js");
            provider.Mappings.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".min.js", "application/javascript"));

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                ContentTypeProvider=provider
            });
```

However, after it runs I can access neither `app.js` nor `app.min.js`.

What's wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that file extension should not contain a dot, so `.min.js` is not a valid file extension. Not sure why you want something from the so-called `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`, looks like it just provides some kind of mapping between file extension name and the corresponding content type (mime type).

Comment: I tried to remove the dot and it still no works. By the way, is there any other way to achieve this feature?@Hopeless

Comment: you remove the dot so it becomes `.minjs`? but your actual file is still `xxx.min.js`? really I still don't get what your issue is. I've just commented about things I see propably wrong. As I understand your `.min.js` file is minified and obfuscated OK but still the user can access your original `.js` file? or he/she can still convert your `.min.js` to the original `.js` file?

Comment: The user still can access my original .js file.@Hopeless

Comment: Well so you need some filter to prevent that from being served, the newly added answer below is fine, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` is only meant to provide a mapping from file extension to the correct MIME type. In order to retrieve the file extension from a file name, it will do the following:

```cs
private static string? GetExtension(string path)
{
    int index = path.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (index < 0)
        return null;
    return path.Substring(index);
}
```

It will take the *very last part* of the extension. So with `app.min.js`, the reported file extension will still be `.js` and not `.min.js`, and as such the mapping for `.js` will be required.

Modifying the MIME type mapping in order to disallow certain file extensions is probably not the best strategy. It would be better to modify the underlying file provider itself to handle that.

Alternatively, if you want to prevent access to non-minified JavaScript files, you could also split the middleware to conditionally prevent serving static files for any request to a path that ends with `.js` that is not a `.min.js`:

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.HasValue
    || !ctx.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".js")
    || ctx.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".min.js"), app2 =>
{
    app2.UseStaticFiles();
});
```

Comment: It can not work. Firstly, the ctx.Request.Path doesn't contain EndsWith method, it should be ctx.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith. Secondary, after I run the program, the website can not be accessed anymore.

Comment: Problem solved, it should use the usewhen while not mapwhen.

Comment: @MelonNG That’s right, thanks for the corrections.